# Ubuntu 20.04.01 and Scanning

Tags: 20.04

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.01.  I have a HP Laserjet Pro MFP M28a and I cound scan and print in Ubuntu 18.04.05 but there is some kind of problem with the HP Plug-in that I do not know how to solve because I cannot scan

Comment: Are you sure that you have downloaded and installed the correct driver from HP website.

Comment: Of course I have the hplip-3.20.3 version

Comment: javier@javier-TravelMate-5720:~$ apt-cache policy hplip-gui
hplip-gui:
  Instalados: 3.20.3+dfsg0-2
  Candidato:  3.20.3+dfsg0-2
  Tabla de versión:
 *** 3.20.3+dfsg0-2 500
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: javier@javier-TravelMate-5720:~$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal